# apt-get install with not available packages

Tags: debian, apt

I done a script to automatically download some packages:

```
LIST="tcpdump nmap wifite"

apt-get --ignore-missing install $LIST
```

"Package wifite is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source"

I didn't find a way to force the download of all packages. apt stops from all download because there's a missing package. I can't modify the list.

Also with -f option I can't solve the problem.

using something like:

```
LIST="tcpdump nmap wifite"
for a in $LIST; do apt-get install $a ; done
```

works but it too slow

also with -y doesn't work

Comment: Actually `--ignore-missing` will only work if apt can't download the package, not if the package has been removed from the repo. You could try `apt-get install -y` in your second solution, so it installs automatically.

Comment: -y doesn't work :/

Comment: it works, I just tried doing `apt-get install -y vim` so I didn't have to manually answer y when installing. The goal was to speed up your for loop over the packages, not to solve the initial issue as it can't be solved through regular apt options.

Comment: Also see; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405850/apt-get-ignore-missing-does-not-work

Answer (score 2):

If LIST is defined outside, and you cannot modify it before, you can use sed to drop `wifite` before sending the list to apt-get:

```
LIST="tcpdump nmap wifite"
apt-get --ignore-missing install $(echo $LIST | sed -e 's/wifite//')
```

Comment: I don't know (in the future) about missed packages. I've a long list and I can't change it.